# Datatables - edit cell data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to edit the data of a cell - I have tried:

```
table.fnUpdate("Delete", idx[0], 5)
```

and

```
tableAPI.cell(idx, 5).data("Delete").draw();
```

and neither works

Here is a [JSBin](http://live.datatables.net/rosibace/1/)- if you click "Load Copied Data" and then click on the end column - it will give you the cell data using tableAPI.cell(idx, 5).data() but the updating doesn't work.

This is the full code of the click

```
  $('#tblSORSInstall tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) {



        var tableAPI = $('#tblSORSInstall').DataTable();
        var table = $('#tblSORSInstall').dataTable();

        var data = table.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
        var idx = table.fnGetPosition($(this).closest('tr')[0]);

        var row = $(this).parents("tr")[0];

        var id = table.fnGetData(row.cells[5]);


        alert(tableAPI.cell(idx, 5).data());
        table.fnUpdate("Delete", idx[0], 5)
        tableAPI.cell(idx, 5).data("Delete").draw();

    });
```

I know this is something simple I'm missing so any help would be appreciated

Comment: In your column definitions `columnDefs` fifth column is not tied to any data (`data: null`) and has `defaultContent`, that's why you can't change it. You need to change the logic of your code (make 5th column tied to a data parameter, for example) or use `render` instead of `defaultContent` to make it dynamic. There is also an error in your code, use `idx` instead of `idx[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @Gyrocode.com - you got it in one - I've removed the data: null definition and it's now working :) (if you want to add this as a answer so i can accept it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your column definitions `columnDefs` fifth column is not tied to any data (`data: null`) and has `defaultContent`, that's why you can't change it.

You need to change the logic of your code (make 5th column tied to a data parameter, for example) or use `render` instead of `defaultContent` to make it dynamic.

There is also an error in your code, use `idx` instead of `idx[0]`.